# How would I log in with a .ROBLOSECURITY using roblox api?

Tags: python, cookies, automation, roblox

I am creating a bot that gets all the free items available on the item catalog, I want the person using the bot to just put their roblox cookie into a .txt file, how would I log in with the cookie in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `requests`, then you're most likely using `requests.Session()`. You can simply use `session.cookies`

Code example:

```py
import requests as r

cookie = "" # cookie goes here (accessed via text file)
requestSession = r.Session() # initiate a session
requestSession.cookies[".ROBLOSECURITY"] = cookie
```

Then you can make a request using the `Session` and it will include the ROBLOSECURITY in the headers.

Comment: Okay, so once I add this then the bot would be logged in?